# how to add the same Widget twice to a sidebar?

Tags: widgets, sidebar

I have a sidebar and would like to fill it like this:

[Text]
[Some other Widget]
[Text]

but I can add the Text widget only once to the Sidebar. What can I do to be able to add it more than once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as simple as dragging another text widget from the active widgets into the sidebar and copying the desired text in again. Unless you are having complications?

Comment: Indeed i had some complications - after restarting the browser it worked just fine. thank you!